# Funciones y Menú de opciones

Tags: dev-c++

Buenas disculpen soy nuevo en programación y tengo un problema con un código el objetivo es unir menú con unas funciones ya tengo el código escrito pero no entiendo porque no se ejecuta. Ya comprobé la estructura y creo que esta bien o me falta agregar algo mas o no estoy utilizando bien las variables Este seria el problema

Combine el uso de la instrucción switch y funciones, realizando lo siguiente: Escribir un programa donde se le muestre el siguiente Menú al usuario

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
void areatri(float ba, float al);
void areacua(float ba, float al);
void arearec(float ba, float al);
void pedirDatos

float base, altura;

int main(){
int opcion;
do
{
    cout << "Menu de Opciones"<<endl;
    cout<<"(1) Area de un Triangulo"<<endl;
    cout<<"(2) Area de un Rectangulo" <<endl;
    cout<<"(3) Area de un Cuadrado" <<endl;
    cout<<"(Ingresa una opcion" <<endl;
    cin>> opcion;
    switch (opcion) {
    case 1: cout << pedirDatos();
                    areatri(base, altura);
                    system("pause");
                    break;
    case 2: cout << cout << pedirDatos();
                    areacua(base, altura);
                    system("pause");
                    break;
    case 3: cout << cout << pedirDatos();
                    arearec(base, altura);
                    system("pause");
                    break;
    default: cout << "Opción no válida" << endl;
                    system("pause");
                    break;
    system("cls");
} while (opcion<=3);
getch();
return 0;
}
void pedirDatos(){
cout<<"Ingrese la Base:";
cin>>base; 
cout<<"Ingrese la Altura:";
cin>>altura; 
}
void areatri(float ba, float al)
{
float areatri = (ba*al)/2;
cout<<"Resultado:"<<areatri<<endl;
}
void areacua(float ba, float al)
{
float areacua = (ba*al);
cout<<"Resultado:"<<areacua<<endl;
}
void arearec(float ba, float al)
{
float arearec = (al*ba);
cout<<"Resultado:"<<arearec<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Sugiero que uses `cin.get()` en lugar de `getch`. Y `system("pause")`. Si encuentras algún reemplazo para  `system("cls")` también así tu programa es compatible con diferentes sistemas operativos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te mostraré los errores que encontré en tu código:

Al inicio declaras mal la función `pedirDatos`. Deberías hacerlo así:

```
void pedirDatos();
```

---

Las variables flotantes deben estar encima de la función en donde las usas, porque si esto no es así, nunca los reconocería:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>  
using namespace std;
    
float base, altura; // <-- aquí debería estar
    
void areatri(float ba, float al);
void areacua(float ba, float al);
void arearec(float ba, float al);
void pedirDatos();
```

---

Otro error que me percaté es que en el `case` estás haciendo un `cout` a la función, deberías llamarlo así:

```
    case 1: pedirDatos();
            areatri(base, altura);
            system("pause");
            break;
```

---

También, hubo muchos errores en las llaves, en unas cuantas faltaban cerrarlas.

Mejorando la sintaxis del código resultaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

float base, altura;

void areatri(float ba, float al);
void areacua(float ba, float al);
void arearec(float ba, float al);
void pedirDatos();

void pedirDatos(){
    cout << "Ingrese la Base:";
    cin >> base;
    cout << "Ingrese la Altura:";
    cin >> altura;
}

void areatri(float ba, float al){
    float areatri = (ba * al) / 2;
    cout << "Resultado:" << areatri << endl;
}

void areacua(float ba, float al){
    float areacua = (ba * al);
    cout << "Resultado:" << areacua << endl;
}

void arearec(float ba, float al){
    float arearec = (al * ba);
    cout << "Resultado:" << arearec << endl;
}

int main(){
    int opcion;
    do{
        cout << "Menu de Opciones" << endl;
        cout << "(1) Area de un Triangulo" << endl;
        cout << "(2) Area de un Rectangulo" << endl;
        cout << "(3) Area de un Cuadrado" << endl;
        cout << "Ingresa una opcion: " << endl;
        cin >> opcion;
        switch (opcion){
        case 1:
            pedirDatos();
            areatri(base, altura);
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 2:
            pedirDatos();
            areacua(base, altura);
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3:
            pedirDatos();
            arearec(base, altura);
            system("pause");
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Opción no válida" << endl;
            system("pause");
            break;
            system("cls");
        }
    }
        while (opcion <= 3)
            ;
        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la corrección te lo agradezco

Comment: Por favor exprésate mejor para no producir confusión. Él llama bien a las funciones. El problema está en que declaró mal la función `pedirDatos`.

Comment: A mi me marcaba error al llamar la función de esa manera, solo corregí esa parte y demás observaciones.

Comment: No me entiendes. Deja que lo corrijo y si no te parece bien lo cambias.

Comment: Perfecto, me parece bien.